# How do I trace from my client PC what databases it connects to

Tags: sql-server, odbc, packet-capture, trace, crystalreports

I wonder if there is some way to trace what servers my program using OLEDB tries to connect to.

Problem:

I have a program displaying some reports made in Crystal Reports.
The loading of some reports are really slow when.
My guess is that they have some embedded connection strings which reference a server that does not exist. My guess is that the client tries to use the embedded connections when loading the report.

I would like to know if I can see trace / log these failed connections in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a packet capturing application like `wireshark` (Linux + Windows) or `tcpdump` (Linux). If your server is busy, it may not be easy to recognize the relevant/irrelevant connections.

If you know the port number/protocol, you can write filters to see less traffic.

Comment: Wiresharke gives me a lot of these:

7 0.008877 10.0.2.15 10.0.2.255 NBNS 92 Name query NB SERVERX<00>

The SERVERX is no longer existing but there are about 100 such NBNS queries

Answer (score 1):

you could try to :

1. netstat -a and see which connections your trying to make
2. odbcad32.exe or variant to see which connections you have configured .For Windows 2003: %systemdrive%\SysWoW64\Odbcad32.exe  or run it from Start\Run

Answer (score 0):

`arp -a`

Is another method for figuring out who you are connected to.